# How can I run byobu from xterm at starting?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen, xterm

I set up byobu auto run with the command  `byobu-enable`. It's great when I log in from terminal or ssh, but how can I make xterm attach to it automatically ?
(mate-terminal from Linux mint especially)

Answer (score 2):

[Byobu](http://launchpad.net/byobu) actually installs a desktop application, too.  In classic Gnome (Mint?), this should be under Applications -> Accessories.

When you run [byobu-enable](http://manpg.es/byobu-enable), it places a line at the end of your `~/.profile`.  If you want [byobu](http://manpg.es/byobu) to launch every time you run [xterm](http://manpg.es/xterm), then you should add that line to `~/.bashrc` instead.  Note that if you're using [tmux](http://manpg.es/tmux) (rather than [screen](http://manpg.es/screen)) as your byobu backend, you'll need to unset the `$TMUX` variable too.  Try this:

```
echo "_byobu_sourced=1 TMUX= . /usr/bin/byobu-launch" >> ~/.bashrc
```

*Full disclosure: I am the original author and current maintainer of Byobu.*

Comment: That's very usefull @Dustin. Related to this, is there a way to make the Byobu desktop app use XTerm? E.g. in my Ubuntu system it is using `gnome-terminal.wrapper` and I don't seem to be able to change it.